# How to use Tumblr Api through a proxy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, python-requests, pytumblr

How can I use the Tumblr api through a proxy.
Any help will be appreciated.

I want to use the Tumblr api that's make api calls through a proxy .

Any help on how to achieve that would be highly appreciated .
Thanks.

This is the normal way of using the api without proxy. Is they a way for me to use it with proxy.

```
import pytumblr
client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
    '<consumer_key>',
    '<consumer_secret>',
    '<oauth_token>',
    '<oauth_secret>',
)

client.info() # get information about the authenticating user
client.dashboard() # get the dashboard for the authenticating user
client.likes() # get the likes for the authenticating user
client.following() # get the blogs followed by the authenticating user
# How can I use it with proxy, that's authenticate with proxy.
```

Answer (score 1):

pytumblr use [requests](https://github.com/tumblr/pytumblr/blob/master/pytumblr/request.py#L49) to send HTTP requests.  So you [can](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/?highlight=http_proxy#proxies) set bash environment variables 'HTTP_PROXY' and 'HTTPS_PROXY' like

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:1080" # or socks5
$ export HTTPS_PROXY="http://127.0.0.1:1080"
$ python3 ./tumblr_code.py
```

or

```
import os

os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:1080'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:1080'

// remaining pytumblr codes
```